# Invalid Type '-' in pack?

Tags: perl, user-interface, arguments, tk-toolkit

**note:** I'm writing a GUI using Perl/Tk on Perl 5, by the way.

I tried to execute my code, but to find this error message:

```
COUNT 0
Invalid type '-' in pack at pack2.pl line 62.
```

This is Line 62 in my application:

```
my $be = $f1->BrowseEntry(-label => "Widget $count:",
        -choices => ["right", "left", "top", "bottom"],
        -variable => \$packdirs[$count], -browsecmd => \&repack)
        -pack(-ipady => 5, -side => 'left');
```

I don't see any problem in my code, can anybody help me?

Comment: Show the rest of the statement. Perl line numbers always refer to the containing statement, so the problem could be anywhere between `my` and the next `;`.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/4146298

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
    -pack(-ipady => 5, -side => 'left');
```

I think this should be `->pack`, not `-pack`. Instead of calling the `->pack()` method, you're calling the built-in `pack` function and subtracting the result from `->BrowseEntry`'s return value. That's why you're getting an error.